# Will there ever be an updated Compute Module?

Tags: compute-module

I would really like to build a product with a Compute Module as its core. But the current module is essentially a Raspberry Pi 1 and the computing power would not be sufficient.

When the Compute Module was released I read somewhere that upcoming modules would be mainly pin compatible, so I thought there would be new versions with the Raspberry Pi 2 or 3 processor. 2.5 years later there are still none.

Are there any trustworthy sources claiming there will/will not be new versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only the first [link](http://hackaday.com/2016/07/15/the-raspberry-pi-3-compute-module-is-on-its-way/) I found mentioning it, but yes a new compute module is planned and has been mentioned in several interviews with Eben Upton (head of the Pi Foundation - I don't think it gets more official).

Answer (score 0):

It can be yours, Gov. for the princely sum of around £164 + V.A.T. from [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/raspberry-pi/rpi-compute3-kit/raspberry-pi-compute-module-3/dp/2675719) for a one off CM3 and the Development Kit (they have several hundred in stock as of the time of writing), provided you are a UK company.

As a private person, Farnell will probably direct you to their consumer arm [C.P.C.](http://cpc.farnell.com/raspberry-pi/rpi-compute3-kit/raspberry-pi-compute-module-3/dp/SC14356) who have a few for £125 + V.A.T. at present.  I note that CPC do have the [original CM + Dev Kit](http://cpc.farnell.com/raspberry-pi/rpi-compute-dev-kit/dev-board-bcm2835-compute-module/dp/SC13438) for (£59 + V.A.T.) and you should be able to drop the [CM3](http://cpc.farnell.com/raspberry-pi/rpi-compute3/raspberry-pi-compute-module-3/dp/SC14353) (possibly not the Lite one as that needs an external flash like normal RPi units - although it is possible that a new, common Dev PWB is now offered which takes any of the CM/CM3/CM3Lite types) for £22 + V.A.T. currently into the set up and save a bit more. YMMV, prices can change, other suppliers may be available etc...